# Get a number from certain position in String and then use it for calculations

Tags: php

I'm trying to code a function that will do some mathematical operations. Here's an example:

```
function test($number){
    $result = 5 * $number[2];
    echo $result;
}
```

So if I enter a number "12345", I want to multiply the number at index 2 with 5. So in this case, I should be multiplying 5*3 and get 15.

But I always get 0. I found the error why I'm always getting 0. It's because $number[2] isn't working. So how do I get a number at a certain index and then calculate with it?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you're passing a string as `$number`?

Comment: I posted my actual code if it helps, yes I do always enter a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can get the number by index only of string not of int.

```
test("124"); // working
test(124); // not working
```

Possible solution is this:

```
function test($number){
    $number = "$number";
    $result = 5 * $number[2];
    echo $result;
}

test(124);
```

Comment: @elclanrs no you can't.

Comment: @Matthew if the suggested solution works, please mark it as accepted answer - so others facing a similar problem can find info how to solve it right.

Comment: Of course, I would accept it before but I had to wait a few minutes before accepting :)